# What file have the top priority of the MySQL configuration files?

Tags: mysql

I'm starting in web development and I have Xampp as a local server for tests, and I know that typing mysql --help in the cmd returns some content plus:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf
>   C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini C: \xampp\mysql\my.cnf

I just want to know if I set a configuration say in C:\Windows\my.ini and there is also the same configuration in C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini what of those have the top priority, what overrides what, and also when I must use those my.cnf files, Can I use them in windows?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

> On Windows, MySQL programs read startup options from the following files, in the specified order (top items are used first).

I'll let you go visit the manual to read the specific order.

Configuration values read in later files override those read in earlier files.

You can use either `.ini` or `.cnf` as the file extension.

Comment: I'm on Linux :-(

Comment: @e2-e4 Then you might like to read the documentation I linked to, which does cover options files on Linux. I was answering the question above, which was clearly about Windows.