# which of the many .cnf files is the actual mysql server configuration file?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, webmin

I am trying to configure mysql server but I can not figure out which of the many cnf files is the one I have to actually change?

```
 root@myserver:~$ locate *.cnf |grep mysql
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
```

I have [webmin](https://www.webmin.com/) and [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) installed  btw

Comment: `mysql --help | grep -A1 'Default options are read from the following files in the given order'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What file have the top priority of the MySQL configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118087/what-file-have-the-top-priority-of-the-mysql-configuration-files)

Comment: the other answer in the other questions is not very novice or googler friendly, what you have provided is time saver for someone very anoyed and stressed out as I am right now